# @NamedStoredProcedureQuery NamedQuery of name: procuder not found

Tags: java, jpa, stored-procedures, orm, eclipselink

Greeting for the day..

Please provide me support. 
I am new in Jpa and calling procuder with @NamedStoredProcedureQuery but my code is giving Exception as @NamedStoredProcedureQuery NamedQuery of name: procuder not found

my code is :=

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "TEST1",procedureName = "TEST1",parameters = {    @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "P_CODE", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),               @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "P_DATE", mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),               @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "P_CURSOR", mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class), })
public class AnotherWayOfCallingProcedure implements Serializable 
{
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "todos";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        StoredProcedureQuery addBookNamedStoredProcedure = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("TEST1");
        addBookNamedStoredProcedure.setParameter("P_CODE", "5000");
        addBookNamedStoredProcedure.setParameter("P_DATE", "5/3/2017");
        // Stored procedure call
        List createdBookId = addBookNamedStoredProcedure.getResultList();
         em.close();
    }
}
```

and `persistence.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.app.IptAnchorageAreaMaster</class>
        <class>com.app.AnotherWayOfCallingProcedure</class>
        <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.6.147:1521:orcl" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="aaa_kkk" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="aaa" />
        <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Your annotations must be on entities within the persistence unit for them to get processed.

Comment: thank you for helping its Working correct